# Minion wave clearing

Tags: league-of-legends

I main supp but wanna learn top, so I was wondering how many *ranged minion attacks* can another minion take with full hp. If someone could tag me a link of *base minion hp* and *base minion attack* I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

here are stats:

[Caster (Ranged) Minion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ranged_minion):

> Health
>   290 (+11 at 3 mins, +11.2 at 4.5 mins, +11.4 at 6 mins,...)
>   Attack damage
>   23 (+1 / 90 sec)
>   Attack speed
>   0.670
>   Range
>   550
>   Armor
>   0
>   Magic res.
>   0

For [Melee Minion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Melee_minion):

> Health
>   455 (+15 at 3 mins, +15.2 at 4.5 mins, +15.4 at 6 mins,...)
>   Attack damage
>   12 (+0.5 / 90 sec)
>   Attack speed
>   1.250
>   Range
>   110
>   Armor
>   0
>   Magic res.
>   0

Therefore, assuming no other interference, a Melee Minion takes 20 attacks from a Ranged Minion to die (at base values).

Comment: So it would be around 24 damage each, so it would take 17/18 hits to meeles and 12 for ranged, but I wanna focus more on ranged attacks because sometimes all 3 attack the same minion and bring the most based damage i normally count around 6 to 7 ranged shots before i last hit a minion but it al depends, thanks anyway